# What is SignalR's browser compatibility?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, browser-support

The most I've found online is in the SignalR FAQ, where it is stated that SignalR does not work in IE6/7. However, for legal reasons I need to present to customers a list of supported browsers. Is there such a list of tested browsers for SignalR?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft has published some compatibility data:

[SignalR on ASP.NET: Supported Platforms](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms)

**From the article:**

SignalR can be used in a variety of web browsers, but typically, only the latest two versions are supported.

Applications that use SignalR in browsers must use jQuery version 1.6.4 or major later versions (such as 1.7.2, 1.8.2, or 1.9.1).

SignalR can be used in the following browsers:

- Microsoft Internet Explorer versions 8, 9 and 10. Modern, Desktop, and Mobile versions are supported.
- Mozilla Firefox: current version - 1, both Windows and Mac versions.
- Google Chrome: current version - 1, both Windows and Mac versions.
- Safari: current version - 1, both Mac and iOS versions.
- Opera: current version - 1, Windows only.
- Android browser

Comment: What does "current version - 1" mean?

Comment: Most recently released (non beta) version & the previous (non beta) version

Answer (score 5):

Here's a list of browsers that support Websockets: http://caniuse.com/websockets note that the only version of Internet Explorer that supported Websockets is version 10.

Failing that SignalR will fall back to one of these other methods which should work on earlier IE's. (It worked on my IE 9 for example):

> SignalR uses a fall back to a [long polling mechanism](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YourUsersDontCareIfYouUseWebSockets.aspx) to connect the browser to the
>   server. After an initial negotiation request the following transports
>   are tried in order until a successful connection can be made:
>
> WebSockets (if the both the server and browser indicate they can
>   support websockets) Server Sent Events, aka EventSource (if the
>   browser supports Server Sent Events, which is basically all browsers
>   except Internet Explorer) Forever Frame (for Internet Explorer only)
>   Ajax long polling

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq

Answer (score 4):

Not yet, we're working on it though.

Update:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms