# SignalR not working in IE8

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, signalr, signalr-hub

I am working on SignalR. Everything working fine in all browser except IE8.
Here is my code.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../signalr/hubs"></script>

 $(document).ready(function () {
        var templateId = '@Model.TemplateId';
        var importNotifier = $.connection.runImport;
        importNotifier.client.sendMessage = function (data) {
            UpdateChart(data);
        };
        $.connection.hub.start().done(init);
        function init() {
            importNotifier.server.import(templateId, $("#hdnServerName").val(), '@ViewBag.ServerUserName', '@ViewBag.ServerPassword', '@ViewBag.AuthenticationType', '@ViewBag.DatabaseName');
        }
    });
```

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3) Timestamp: Tue, 22 Sep 2015 07:39:12 UTC
>
> Message: Expected identifier, string or number Line: 88 Char: 13 Code:
>   0 URI: http://localhost:8092/signalr/hubs
>
> Message: Expected identifier Line: 279 Char: 39 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://localhost:8092/Graph/Graph/?TemplateId=27&IsUse=0

I am not able to understand why it is not working.
I tried to insert http://localhost:8092/signalr/hubs to browser and its allow me to download.

Answer (score 0):

I websockets are not supported in IE8. First version that works with websockets is IE10.

Here's a list of browsers that support(or not) websockets: http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

Comment: Hi Erik thanks for reply. I check your link. Can you please check this link
[SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms). So I am confused between this two answer.

Comment: Hi Urvi, I checked that and also found this : https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq You can see more regarding SignalR on IE following this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869745/what-is-signalrs-browser-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved issue.I follow following steps

1. uninstall all packages which is required for SignalR.
2. Install again required packages.

I follow this step. because I was in impression that may there was some dependency issue.
Then also my code was not working

1. finally I change my method name "Import" to "InsertingData"

and its working now.
So I can not conclude here that only name creates any problem (may be import is keyword in ie8) or there is some issue with dependency also.